JS and images fail to load, but all other static files load right (Express JS, Nginx)
This issue has brought me to my knees, it's so bizarre I can't find anything online and my llama3 ai can't figure it out either.
I am making a simple chat app with socket.io, and im hosting it on the same port as the web server.
The issue is that my website will load EJS, HTML, and CSS just fine, but images load maybe 20% of the time and JS never loads.
For example, I found this cool matrix text js I can use as my websites canvas, I go to my website, everything loads but the js. other pages have broken images and js. I have cleared my cache to double check its JUST the js
Everything works just fine on my home network.
Im running the server on a single board computer with rasbian lite.
My Express.js
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const express = require("express");
var app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const path = require('path')
//var router = express.Router();

app.use(express.static('views'))

import { getMessages, getMessage, createMessage} from "./database.js"

const users = {}


io.on("connection", socket => {
    socket.on("new-user", async (name) => {
        let name2 = await getMessage(name)
        if (name2 !== "fail") {
            socket.emit("verify", "pass")
            socket.broadcast.emit("user-added", name2)
            console.log(" new user connected:", name2,"")
            users[socket.id] = name2
        } else {
            socket.emit("verify", "fail")
            console.log(" CONNECTION FROM "${name}" REFUSED ")
            delete users[socket.id]
            socket.disconnect(0);
        }
    })
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('user-disconnect', users[socket.id])
        delete users[socket.id]
    })
    socket.on("send-chat-message", message => {
        socket.broadcast.emit("broadcast-message", {message: message, name: users[socket.id]})
        console.log(message)
    })
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index.ejs")
});
app.get("/network", async (reaq, res) => {
    res.render("network.ejs")
})

app.get("/messages", async (req, res) => {
    const messages = await getMessage(1)
    res.send(messages)
})

server.listen(4000, () => console.log('http://localhost:4000/'));
I also want to note that I don't think the socket.io server works, but I can't properly test it because I can't load my client.js
My nginx config: (in sites available)
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        root /home/honeypot/WebServer/views;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ @app;
        }
        location @app {
        root /home/honeypot/WebServer/views;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_buffering off;    
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}

views is my static files folder
The timeline in safari, the js file is stuck on loading
I used curl server.com/something.js it it worked once and never again
I've been trouble shooting this for 2 weeks. I might just abandon everything web and learn C.
Thanks in advance for any help.
I have tried messing with permissions, hammering every nginx configuration I could (I don't understand nginx that much)
Just now saw this:
I enabled some kind of logging and got this
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. weird
